# ipython 0.10.2 crashes with turbogears paster shell

Tags: ipython, paster, turbogears2

turbogears has intergrated paster shell with Ipython.
for this to work you have to use version 0.10.2 (or less)

so in the virtualenv I did:

```
pip install ipython=0.10.2
```

when I run paster shell I get:

Oops, IPython crashed. We do our best to make it stable, but...

```
A crash report was automatically generated with the following information:
  - A verbatim copy of the crash traceback.
  - A copy of your input history during this session.
  - Data on your current IPython configuration.
```

here is the Ipython crash repost

---

```
IPython post-mortem report

IPython version: 0.10.2 

Platform info  : os.name -> nt, sys.platform -> win32

***************************************************************************

Current user configuration structure:

{'Version': 0,
 '__allownew': True,
 'alias': [],
 'args': [],
 'autocall': 1,
 'autoedit_syntax': 0,
 'autoexec': [],
 'autoindent': 1,
 'automagic': 1,
 'banner': 1,
 'c': '',
 'cache_size': 1000,
 'classic': 0,
 'color_info': 1,
 'colors': 'Linux',
 'confirm_exit': 1,
 'debug': 0,
 'deep_reload': 0,
 'editor': '0',
 'execfile': [],
 'execute': [''],
 'gthread': 0,
 'help': 0,
 'import_all': [],
 'import_mod': [],
 'import_some': [[]],
 'include': [],
 'interact': 0,
 'ipythondir': u'c:\\users\\alonisser\\_ipython',
 'log': 0,
 'logfile': '',
 'logplay': '',
 'magic_docstrings': 0,
 'messages': 1,
 'multi_line_specials': 1,
 'nosep': 0,
 'object_info_string_level': 0,
 'opts': Struct({'__allownew': True}),
 'pdb': 0,
 'pprint': 1,
 'profile': '',
 'prompt_in1': 'In [\\#]: ',
 'prompt_in2': '   .\\D.: ',
 'prompt_out': 'Out[\\#]: ',
 'prompts_pad_left': 1,
 'pydb': 0,
 'pylab': 0,
 'pylab_import_all': 1,
 'q4thread': 0,
 'qthread': 0,
 'quick': 0,
 'quiet': 0,
 'rcfile': 'ipythonrc.ini',
 'readline': 1,
 'readline_merge_completions': 1,
 'readline_omit__names': 0,
 'readline_parse_and_bind': ['tab: complete',
                             '"\\C-l": possible-completions',
                             'set show-all-if-ambiguous on',
                             '"\\C-o": tab-insert',
                             '"\\M-i": "    "',
                             '"\\M-o": "\\d\\d\\d\\d"',
                             '"\\M-I": "\\d\\d\\d\\d"',
                             '"\\C-r": reverse-search-history',
                             '"\\C-s": forward-search-history',
                             '"\\C-p": history-search-backward',
                             '"\\C-n": history-search-forward',
                             '"\\e[A": history-search-backward',
                             '"\\e[B": history-search-forward',
                             '"\\C-k": kill-line',
                             '"\\C-u": unix-line-discard'],
 'readline_remove_delims': '-/~',
 'screen_length': 0,
 'separate_in': '\\n',
 'separate_out': '0',
 'separate_out2': '0',
 'system_header': 'IPython system call: ',
 'system_verbose': 1,
 'term_title': 1,
 'tk': 0,
 'upgrade': 0,
 'wildcards_case_sensitive': 1,
 'wthread': 0,
 'wxversion': '0',
 'xmode': 'Context'}

***************************************************************************

Crash traceback:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError               Python 2.7.4: c:\dev\envs\agents\Scripts\python.exe
                                                   Tue Jun 11 15:39:42 2013
A problem occured executing Python code.  Here is the sequence of function
calls leading up to the error, with the most recent (innermost) call last.

c:\dev\envs\agents\Scripts\ipython-script.py in <module>()
      1 
      2 
      3 
      4 
      5 
      6 
      7 
----> 8 
        global load_entry_point = <function load_entry_point at 0x022EBBF0>
      9 #!c:\dev\envs\agents\Scripts\python.exe
     10 # EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'ipython==0.10.2','console_scripts','ipython'
     11 __requires__ = 'ipython==0.10.2'
     12 import sys
     13 from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
     14 
     15 sys.exit(
     16    load_entry_point('ipython==0.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
     17 )
     18 
     19 
     20 
     21 
     22 
     23 
     24 
     25 
     26 
     27 
     28 
     29 
     30 
     31 

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipapi.pyc in launch_new_instance(user_ns=None, shellclass=None)
    541 
    542     def check_hotname(self,name):
    543         if name in self.hotnames:
    544             self.debug_stack( "HotName '%s' caught" % name)
    545 
    546 
    547 def launch_new_instance(user_ns = None,shellclass = None):
    548     """ Make and start a new ipython instance.
    549     
    550     This can be called even without having an already initialized 
    551     ipython session running.
    552     
    553     This is also used as the egg entry point for the 'ipython' script.
    554     
    555     """
--> 556     ses = make_session(user_ns,shellclass)
    557     ses.mainloop()
    558 
    559 
    560 def make_user_ns(user_ns = None):
    561     """Return a valid user interactive namespace.
    562 
    563     This builds a dict with the minimal information needed to operate as a
    564     valid IPython user namespace, which you can pass to the various embedding
    565     classes in ipython.
    566 
    567     This API is currently deprecated. Use ipapi.make_user_namespaces() instead
    568     to make both the local and global namespace objects simultaneously.
    569 
    570     :Parameters:
    571         user_ns : dict-like, optional

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipapi.pyc in make_session(user_ns=None, shellclass=None)
    669 
    670 def make_session(user_ns = None, shellclass = None):
    671     """Makes, but does not launch an IPython session.
    672     
    673     Later on you can call obj.mainloop() on the returned object.
    674 
    675     Inputs:
    676 
    677       - user_ns(None): a dict to be used as the user's namespace with initial
    678       data.
    679     
    680     WARNING: This should *not* be run when a session exists already."""
    681 
    682     import IPython.Shell
    683     if shellclass is None:
--> 684         return IPython.Shell.start(user_ns)
    685     return shellclass(user_ns = user_ns)
    686 
    687 
    688 
    689 
    690 
    691 
    692 
    693 
    694 
    695 
    696 
    697 
    698 
    699 

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.pyc in start(user_ns=None)
   1227             th_mode = special_opts.pop()
   1228         except KeyError:
   1229             th_mode = 'tkthread'
   1230         return th_shell[th_mode]
   1231 
   1232 
   1233 # This is the one which should be called by external code.
   1234 def start(user_ns = None):
   1235     """Return a running shell instance, dealing with threading options.
   1236 
   1237     This is a factory function which will instantiate the proper IPython shell
   1238     based on the user's threading choice.  Such a selector is needed because
   1239     different GUI toolkits require different thread handling details."""
   1240 
   1241     shell = _select_shell(sys.argv)
-> 1242     return shell(user_ns = user_ns)
   1243 
   1244 # Some aliases for backwards compatibility
   1245 IPythonShell = IPShell
   1246 IPythonShellEmbed = IPShellEmbed
   1247 #************************ End of file <Shell.py> ***************************
   1248 
   1249 
   1250 
   1251 
   1252 
   1253 
   1254 
   1255 
   1256 
   1257 

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\Shell.pyc in __init__(self=<IPython.Shell.IPShell instance>, argv=None, user_ns=None, user_global_ns=None, debug=1, shell_class=<class 'IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell'>)
     58 # Default timeout for waiting for multithreaded shells (in seconds)
     59 GUI_TIMEOUT = 10
     60 
     61 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     62 # This class is trivial now, but I want to have it in to publish a clean
     63 # interface. Later when the internals are reorganized, code that uses this
     64 # shouldn't have to change.
     65 
     66 class IPShell:
     67     """Create an IPython instance."""
     68     
     69     def __init__(self,argv=None,user_ns=None,user_global_ns=None,
     70                  debug=1,shell_class=InteractiveShell):
     71         self.IP = make_IPython(argv,user_ns=user_ns,
     72                                user_global_ns=user_global_ns,
---> 73                                debug=debug,shell_class=shell_class)
        global For = undefined
        global more = undefined
        global details = undefined
        global see = undefined
        global the = undefined
        global __call__ = undefined
        global method = undefined
        global below. = undefined
     74 
     75     def mainloop(self,sys_exit=0,banner=None):
     76         self.IP.mainloop(banner)
     77         if sys_exit:
     78             sys.exit()
     79 
     80 #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     81 def kill_embedded(self,parameter_s=''):
     82     """%kill_embedded : deactivate for good the current embedded IPython.
     83 
     84     This function (after asking for confirmation) sets an internal flag so that
     85     an embedded IPython will never activate again.  This is useful to
     86     permanently disable a shell that is being called inside a loop: once you've
     87     figured out what you needed from it, you may then kill it and the program
     88     will then continue to run without the interactive shell interfering again.

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipmaker.pyc in make_IPython(argv=[r'c:\dev\envs\agents\Scripts\ipython-script.py'], user_ns=None, user_global_ns=None, debug=1, rc_override=None, shell_class=<class 'IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell'>, embedded=False, **kw={})
    506     # tweaks. Basically options which affect other options. I guess this
    507     # should just be written so that options are fully orthogonal and we
    508     # wouldn't worry about this stuff!
    509 
    510     if IP_rc.classic:
    511         IP_rc.quick = 1
    512         IP_rc.cache_size = 0
    513         IP_rc.pprint = 0
    514         IP_rc.prompt_in1 = '>>> '
    515         IP_rc.prompt_in2 = '... '
    516         IP_rc.prompt_out = ''
    517         IP_rc.separate_in = IP_rc.separate_out = IP_rc.separate_out2 = '0'
    518         IP_rc.colors = 'NoColor'
    519         IP_rc.xmode = 'Plain'
    520 
--> 521     IP.pre_config_initialization()
    522     # configure readline
    523 
    524     # update exception handlers with rc file status
    525     otrap.trap_out()  # I don't want these messages ever.
    526     IP.magic_xmode(IP_rc.xmode)
    527     otrap.release_out()
    528 
    529     # activate logging if requested and not reloading a log
    530     if IP_rc.logplay:
    531         IP.magic_logstart(IP_rc.logplay + ' append')
    532     elif  IP_rc.logfile:
    533         IP.magic_logstart(IP_rc.logfile)
    534     elif IP_rc.log:
    535         IP.magic_logstart()
    536 

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\iplib.pyc in pre_config_initialization(self=<IPython.iplib.InteractiveShell object>)
    820                           self.user_ns,  # globals
    821                           # Skip our own frame in searching for locals:
    822                           sys._getframe(depth+1).f_locals # locals
    823                           ))
    824 
    825     def pre_config_initialization(self):
    826         """Pre-configuration init method
    827 
    828         This is called before the configuration files are processed to
    829         prepare the services the config files might need.
    830         
    831         self.rc already has reasonable default values at this point.
    832         """
    833         rc = self.rc
    834         try:
--> 835             self.db = pickleshare.PickleShareDB(rc.ipythondir + "/db")
        global Optional = undefined
        global inputs = undefined
    836         except exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError:
    837             print "Your ipythondir can't be decoded to unicode!"
    838             print "Please set HOME environment variable to something that"
    839             print r"only has ASCII characters, e.g. c:\home"
    840             print "Now it is",rc.ipythondir
    841             sys.exit()
    842         self.shadowhist = IPython.history.ShadowHist(self.db)
    843 
    844     def post_config_initialization(self):
    845         """Post configuration init method
    846 
    847         This is called after the configuration files have been processed to
    848         'finalize' the initialization."""
    849 
    850         rc = self.rc

c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\Extensions\pickleshare.pyc in __init__(self=PickleShareDB('c:\users\alonisser\_ipython\db'), root=u'c:\\users\\alonisser\\_ipython/db')
     38 import cPickle as pickle
     39 import UserDict
     40 import warnings
     41 import glob
     42 
     43 def gethashfile(key):
     44     return ("%02x" % abs(hash(key) % 256))[-2:]
     45 
     46 _sentinel = object()
     47 
     48 class PickleShareDB(UserDict.DictMixin):
     49     """ The main 'connection' object for PickleShare database """
     50     def __init__(self,root):
     51         """ Return a db object that will manage the specied directory"""
     52         self.root = Path(root).expanduser().abspath()
---> 53         if not self.root.isdir():
     54             self.root.makedirs()
     55         # cache has { 'key' : (obj, orig_mod_time) }
     56         self.cache = {}
     57         
     58 
     59     def __getitem__(self,key):
     60         """ db['key'] reading """
     61         fil = self.root / key
     62         try:
     63             mtime = (fil.stat()[stat.ST_MTIME])
     64         except OSError:
     65             raise KeyError(key)
     66 
     67         if fil in self.cache and mtime == self.cache[fil][1]:
     68             return self.cache[fil][0]

TypeError: _isdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

***************************************************************************

History of session input:

*** Last line of input (may not be in above history):
```

any ideas?

I'm a windows 7 user, and the usual (outside the virtualenv) Ipython 0.13.2 works fine.

**Edit:** to clarify: I did uninstall and install, after the uninstall there are no Ipython folders or files in the env\lib\site-packages folder

after an install, the same errors return

Answer (score 0):

Do you have both installed ? Traceback seem incoherent, as if you had stale pyc file and 0.10.2 was picking up 0.13.1 files.

Comment: both installed, one is the system default and one in the virtualenv. a stale pyc is a possibility (since I copied some of the virtualenv). where to look for it?

Comment: See the tracebacks, .pyc files like `c:\dev\envs\agents\lib\site-packages\IPython\ipmaker.pyc` for example. Not lots of experiences with windows

Comment: I'm quite sure this isn't the problem, since after uninstalling Ipython those files don't exist any longer (checked that) but after a reinstall I'm getting the same errors

Comment: problem is that traceback is source seem to call `self.root.isdir():` wherease Traceback complains about `_isdir()` are you autoloading extension on startup ? Why the need of 0.10.2 also ?

Comment: don't load any Extensions (I know of). the need for 0.10.2 as explained in the question is because this version of Ipython is integrated with pylons (and tg built over it) command: ```paster shell```

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, read the question too fast. Try removing your ipython profile (back-it up first). The error appear in an extension so the embeded shell might be loading custom extensions that conflict with how new versions store history db.

Comment: on windows and 0.10.2 I'm not sure. should be `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default` which  might change for embeded shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting your profile folder?
In Linux it is somewhere like `$HOME/.ipython`?

That always helps me when I have problems with IPython.